# SQL Server Insert using case statement to return no rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if it's possible to write an insert using fairly complicated case logic but insert no rows if none of the case predicates are true, This also means I don't want to insert a null. The select case wont be retrieving data from a table

e.g.

```
DECLARE @tabErrors TABLE (errorMessage NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @intType INT
DECLARE @intVal INT

INSERT @tabErrors
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN @intType = 1 AND @intVal > 100
      THEN 'Some Error'
   WHEN @intType = 2 AND @intVal > 200
      THEN 'Some Other Error'
   ELSE <NO ROWS> END

IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tabErrors = 0
   -- Continue with processing
```

Unfortunately I can't amend the statement checking the count (i.e. to put in a where `errorMessage IS NOT NULL`)

Is there a way to do this or should I resort to separating the case into multiple if statements?

Comment: case expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `CASE` expression (`Case` (`Switch`) statements don't exist in T-SQL) returns a Scalar value, it has no control other how many rows a `SELECT` returns, If you want to control if a row is return, you need to do so in the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @intType = 1 AND @intVal > 100 THEN 'Some Error'
            WHEN @intType = 2 AND @intVal > 200 THEN 'Some Other Error'
       END AS YourAlias
WHERE (@intType = 1 AND @intVal > 100)
   OR (@intType = 2 AND @intVal > 200);
```

Comment: Documentation of the behaviour mentioned can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15